# why does last -i show random IP addresses?

Tags: linux

I was checking out recent logins, and last -i showed logins from unfamiliar IP addresses. In checking what processes these logins were running, it became apparent that these logins were xterm windows that I initiated. Logins from a remote host via ssh showed the correct source IP address. I'm running openSuSE 11.1 and the icewm window manager. Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can avoid incorrect IP addresses? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give examples of what you mean by 'incorrect'?

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see what these IPs are really. They could be local IPs which you would overwise may not be aware of before (e.g. 127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

On my system `last -i` simply displays `0.0.0.0` for non-remote logins.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some output from last -i.

```
chuck    pts/5        160.79.9.0       Thu Dec 17 12:31   still logged in
chuck    pts/4        204.192.0.0      Thu Dec 17 10:20   still logged in  
chuck    pts/0        182.32.1.0       Wed May  6 11:19   still logged in   
chuck    pts/3        123.104.4.0      Thu Mar 19 13:20   still logged in   
chuck    pts/1        158.201.4.0      Thu Mar 19 13:20   still logged in
```

None of these are local IPs. Also, all of the incorrect IPs (there are more than the ones I show) end in .0. My local logins (into a tty as opposed to a pts) show a source of 0.0.0.0.