# Reasons for missing IP info in `last` output on pts logins?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, login, terminal

I have five CentOS 6 linux systems at work, and encountered a rather strange issue that only seems to happen with *my userid* across all the linux systems I have... This is an example of the problem from entries I excepted from the `last` command...

```
mpenning pts/19                        Fri Nov 16 10:32 - 10:35  (00:03)
mpenning pts/17                        Fri Nov 16 10:21 - 10:42  (00:21)
bill     pts/15       sol-bill.local   Fri Nov 16 10:19 - 10:36  (00:16)
mpenning pts/1        192.0.2.91       Fri Nov 16 10:17 - 10:49 (12+00:31)
kkim14   pts/14       192.0.2.225      Thu Nov 15 18:02 - 15:17 (4+21:15)
gduarte  pts/10       192.0.2.135      Thu Nov 15 12:33 - 08:10 (11+19:36)
gduarte  pts/9        192.0.2.135      Thu Nov 15 12:31 - 08:10 (11+19:38)
kkim14   pts/0        :0.0             Thu Nov 15 12:27 - 15:17 (5+02:49)
gduarte  pts/6        192.0.2.135      Thu Nov 15 11:44 - 08:10 (11+20:25)
kkim14   pts/13       192.0.2.225      Thu Nov 15 09:56 - 15:17 (5+05:20)
kkim14   pts/12       192.0.2.225      Thu Nov 15 08:28 - 15:17 (5+06:49)
kkim14   pts/11       192.0.2.225      Thu Nov 15 08:26 - 15:17 (5+06:50)
dspencer pts/8        192.0.2.130      Wed Nov 14 18:24   still logged in
mpenning pts/18       alpha-console-1. Mon Nov 12 14:41 - 14:46  (00:04)
```

You can see two of my pts login entries above that do not have a source IP address associated with them.  My CentOS machines have as many as six other users that share the systems. Approximately 10% of my logins see this issue, but *no other usernames exhibit this behavior*.  There is no entry in `/var/log/secure` for the entries without a source IP address.

### Questions

Given the kind of scripts I keep on these systems (which control much of our network infrastructure), I'm a little spooked by this and would like to understand what would cause my logins to occasionally miss source addresses.

- Why does `last -i` show `0.0.0.0` for *pts line entries* (also see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/95570/78702))
- Is there anything (other than malicious activity) that would reasonably explain the behavior?
- Other than bash history timestamping, are there other things I can do to track the issue down?

### Informational

Since this started happening, I enabled `bash` history time-stamping (i.e. `HISTTIMEFORMAT="%y-%m-%d %T "` in `.bash_profile`) and also added a [few other bash history hacks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48116/6766); however, that does not give clues to what happened during the previous occurrences.

All the systems run CentOS 6.3...

```
[mpenning@typo ~]$ uname -a
Linux typo.local 2.6.32-279.9.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 25 21:43:11 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@typo ~]$
```

### EDIT

If I use `last -i mpenning`, I see entries like this...

```
mpenning pts/19       0.0.0.0          Fri Nov 16 10:32 - 10:35  (00:03)
mpenning pts/17       0.0.0.0          Fri Nov 16 10:21 - 10:42  (00:21)
```

Note for those trying to answer: **I have not logged in with the `screen` command or the GUI**.  All my logins are from SSH; to receive the bounty award, you must cite *authoritative* references to explain the `last -i` `0.0.0.0` entries sourced only via SSH.

### EDIT 2 (for ewwhite's questions)

**`/etc/resolv.conf`** (note that I used `.local` addrs in `last` output above to hide my company's info)

```
[mpenning@sasmars network]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.0.2.40
nameserver 192.0.2.60
domain mycompany.com
search mycompany.com
[mpenning@sasmars network]$
```

**`/etc/hosts`** info (note that this customized hosts file only exists on one of the machines that has these problems)

```
[mpenning@sasmars network]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
192.0.2.44      sasmars.mycompany.com sasmars
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6

## Temporary kludge until I add reverse hostname mappings...
## Firewalls
192.0.2.254     a2-inet-fw1
192.0.2.253     a2-inet-fw2
192.0.2.254     a2-wan-fw1
192.0.2.253     a2-wan-fw2
192.0.2.201     a2-fab-fw1
192.0.2.202     a2-fab-fw2
192.0.2.203     t1-eds-fw1
192.0.2.42      sasvpn
192.0.2.246     sasasa1
192.0.2.10      sasoutfw1
## Wireless
192.0.2.6       saswcs1
192.0.2.2       l2wlc3
192.0.2.4       l2wlc4
192.0.2.12      f2wlc5
192.0.2.16      f2wlc6
192.0.2.14      f2wlc1
192.0.2.8       f2wlc2
[mpenning@sasmars network]$
```

**`sftp` Output from `/var/log/secure`***

```
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_authenticate: called (pam_tacplus v1.3.7)
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_authenticate: user [mpenning] obtained
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: tacacs_get_password: called
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: tacacs_get_password: obtained password
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_authenticate: password obtained
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_authenticate: tty [ssh] obtained
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_authenticate: rhost [192.0.2.91] obtained
Dec 26 10:36:37 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_authenticate: trying srv 0
Dec 26 10:36:38 sasmars sshd[26016]: Accepted password for mpenning from 192.0.2.91 port 55118 ssh2
Dec 26 10:36:38 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_setcred: called (pam_tacplus v1.3.7)
Dec 26 10:36:38 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user mpenning by (uid=0)
Dec 26 10:36:38 sasmars sshd[26018]: pam_sm_setcred: called (pam_tacplus v1.3.7)
Dec 26 10:36:38 sasmars sshd[26018]: subsystem request for sftp
Dec 26 10:37:20 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user mpenning
Dec 26 10:37:20 sasmars sshd[26016]: pam_sm_setcred: called (pam_tacplus v1.3.7)
```

### FINAL RESOLUTION

See [*my answer below*](https://serverfault.com/a/462779/78702)

Comment: Are they all connecting via ssh? I have a number of large multiuser CentOS 6.x systems. I'll see if I can see the same thing there.

Comment: @ewwhite, thank you... all logins should be ssh (and occasionally via GUI console, but I only login from the GUI when turning the box up).  No other remote login protocol is enabled.

Comment: Does the output of `last -i mpenning` show the blanks?

Comment: Oh, right.. I need to replicate this on an EL6.3 server...

Comment: Can you provide the login output from /var/log/secure and /var/log/messages ? I believe that the IP value is a parameter passed in via PAM. Does PAM show the IP properly?

Comment: You want to know why the hostname/ip is blank? Or you want to know why(what cause) those entries are there?

Comment: @JohnSiu, I am trying to figure out what causes these blank entries; as part of finding that I'm interested in how the blank entries get there

Comment: @MikePennington Good the heard that, as that is what I am after. Check (4) of my updated answer.

Comment: Just want to add: on my systems(RHEL) - if users initiated xterm from a VNC session, it will get recorded as 0.0.0.0. So every new xterm will be  recorded 0.0.0.0 with the related pts number. So its a non-remote connection.

Comment: @Mlfe, the `0.0.0.0` entries have *no* corresponding entry in `/var/log/secure`... this is part of what is so disturbing

Comment: @MikePennington Do you have some ssh tunnel setup in your putty?

Comment: @JohnSiu, there are no putty tunnels

Comment: @MikePennington In SuperPutty GUI, there is a Commands bar, expend the pull down list and see if you recognize anything that may open a new session.

Comment: @MikePennington I know bounty is close, but did you track down the source(process/program) creating the entries?

Comment: Yes, actually I found the problem... thank you.  Please see [*my answer below*](http://serverfault.com/a/462779/78702)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `script` behavior differences between RedHat and Debian

### Linked Libraries

**CentOS 6.3 - script (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)**

```
#ldd /usr/bin/script

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff077ff000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f309f5d1000)
libutempter.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libutempter.so.0 (0x00007f309f3cf000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f309f03b000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f309f7e1000)
```

**Ubuntu 12.04 - script (util-linux 2.20.1)**

```
#ldd /usr/bin/script

linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff375ff000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fc0d7ab0000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc0d76f1000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc0d7cdc000)
```

### PTY

Base on [upstream source code](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/), `script` from both versions do open new pty. Following is test.

**Ubuntu 12.04**

```
john@U64D211:~/tmp$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  5  8  ptmx
john@U64D211:~/tmp$ script
Script started, file is typescript
john@U64D211:~/tmp$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  2  5  8  ptmx
john@U64D211:~/tmp$ last -i
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:09   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:08 - 09:52  (00:44)    
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:50 - 01:42  (00:52)    
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:48 - 01:43  (00:54)    

wtmp begins Tue Jan  1 20:48:28 2013
john@U64D211:~/tmp$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
john@U64D211:~/tmp$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  5  8  ptmx
john@U64D211:~/tmp$
```

Ubuntu 12.04 `script` did open a new pts(2). It just did not update `/var/log/wtmp`.

**CentOS 6**

I am skipping the test as we already know that `script` do open pty and register with wtmp.

### **libutemper**

- Project: http://freecode.com/projects/libutempter
- Description: libutempter provides a library interface for terminal emulators such as screen and xterm to record user sessions to utmp and wtmp files.

So the main difference seems to be the extra library(`libutempter.so.0`) CentOS `script` linked with.

**Test with Ubuntu 12.04**

*Compiling `script` with libutempter*

```
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1$ sudo apt-get install libutempter-dev
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1$ ./configure --with-utempter
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1$ make
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1$ cd term-utils/
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ ldd ./script
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff54dff000)
libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f289e635000)
libutempter.so.0 => /usr/lib/libutempter.so.0 (0x00007f289e432000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f289e072000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f289e861000)
```

*Testing*

Before running `script`

```
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  5  8  ptmx
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ last -i
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:09   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:08 - 10:37  (01:28)    
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:50 - 01:42  (00:52)    
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:48 - 01:43  (00:54)    

wtmp begins Tue Jan  1 20:48:28 2013
```

Within `script`

```
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ ./script
Script started, file is typescript
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  2  5  8  ptmx
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ last -i
john     pts/2        0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 10:37   still logged in   
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:09   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:08 - 10:37  (01:29)    
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:50 - 01:42  (00:52)    
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:48 - 01:43  (00:54)    

wtmp begins Tue Jan  1 20:48:28 2013
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
```

After `script` end

```
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  5  8  ptmx
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ last -i
john     pts/2        0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 10:37 - 10:37  (00:00)    
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:09   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sat Jan  5 09:08 - 10:37  (01:29)    
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:50 - 01:42  (00:52)    
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 00:48 - 01:43  (00:54)    

wtmp begins Tue Jan  1 20:48:28 2013
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils$ last
john     pts/2                         Sat Jan  5 10:37 - 10:37  (00:00)    
john     pts/0        :0               Sat Jan  5 09:09   still logged in   
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-35-generic Sat Jan  5 09:08 - 10:38  (01:30)    
john     pts/0        :0               Thu Jan  3 00:50 - 01:42  (00:52)    
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-35-generic Thu Jan  3 00:48 - 01:43  (00:54)    

wtmp begins Tue Jan  1 20:48:28 2013
```

**The root cause of emtpy hostname**

And yes, `script.c` do create the `wtmp` entry with empty hostname. Look at following code block in `util-linux-2.20.1/term-utils/script.c` Line:245-247

```
#ifdef HAVE_LIBUTEMPTER
    utempter_add_record(master, NULL);
#endif
```

Base on `libutempter-1.1.5/utempter.h`

```
extern int utempter_add_record (int master_fd, const char *hostname);
```

So `script.c` is actually passing empty hostname into `utempter_add_record`.

**RedHat Backport**

The interesting thing is, upstream `util-linux-ng-2.17.2` actually does not support `libutempter`. Seems Redhat decided to added that support back.

```
john@U64D211:~/tmp/util-linux-ng-2.17.2$ ./configure --help|grep utemp
```

The above command return empty result.

### Conclusion

So the difference in behavior between the two distros is not a bug, but a choice. RedHat decided to support that feature, while Debian skipped it.

Comment: What about CentOS 5?

Comment: @ewwhite Can you give me the `coreutils` rpm version CentOS 5 is using? I have to check the source code.

Comment: No need. `libutempter` is not linked in EL4 (via `ldd`), but it *is* linked in the EL5 and EL6 `script` command. This feature change has likely been in place for Red Hat-like systems since the 2007 introduction of RHEL 5. `coreutils` on EL4 is version 5.2.1. On EL5 it's version 5.97.

Comment: I see. BTW, `script` is in util-linux.

Comment: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=477753

Comment: @lain It is not default compile option for `util-linux 2.20.1`. Option `--with-utempter` is needed during source configuration for `script` to update wtmp.

Comment: @JohnSiu: Yes, that's the reason for the difference, it seems to me that they fixed the reported bug and (unintentionally) created a new one.

Comment: very interesting find, thanks for digging this up! Lets se what RHEL does with the info

Comment: My bet is RHEL will reply with : As designed [CLOSED] @.@

Comment: at a minimum, this should be documentation bug... we need some indication that you will get blank wtmp entries when you use the centos version of script...

Comment: That will be `linux-util`. Updated. See section `The root cause of emtpy hostname`. Seems to be lazy coding.

Answer (score 12):

This looks absolutely puzzling to me. Either it should use some DNS name or IP address. I checked the `last.c` file also but I still can't find why it is not showing anything. Probably given some time, I can figure out the part about 0.0.0.0.

```
int dns_lookup(char *result, int size, int useip, int32_t *a)
307 {
308     struct sockaddr_in  sin;
309     struct sockaddr_in6 sin6;
310     struct sockaddr     *sa;
311     int         salen, flags;
312     int         mapped = 0;
313 
314     flags = useip ? NI_NUMERICHOST : 0;
315 
316     /*
317      *  IPv4 or IPv6 ?
318      *  1. If last 3 4bytes are 0, must be IPv4
319      *  2. If IPv6 in IPv4, handle as IPv4
320      *  3. Anything else is IPv6
321      *
322      *  Ugly.
323      */
324     if (a[0] == 0 && a[1] == 0 && a[2] == htonl (0xffff))
325         mapped = 1;
326 
327     if (mapped || (a[1] == 0 && a[2] == 0 && a[3] == 0)) {
328         /* IPv4 */
329         sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
330         sin.sin_port = 0;
331         sin.sin_addr.s_addr = mapped ? a[3] : a[0];
332         sa = (struct sockaddr *)&sin;
333         salen = sizeof(sin);
334     } else {
335         /* IPv6 */
336         memset(&sin6, 0, sizeof(sin6));
337         sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
338         sin6.sin6_port = 0;
339         memcpy(sin6.sin6_addr.s6_addr, a, 16);
340         sa = (struct sockaddr *)&sin6;
341         salen = sizeof(sin6);
342     }
343 
344     return getnameinfo(sa, salen, result, size, NULL, 0, flags);
345 }
```

The two global variables used in the context are these.

```
int usedns = 0;     /* Use DNS to lookup the hostname. */
72 int useip = 0;       /* Print IP address in number format */
```

So, in theory, it should either use dns or IP.

I will see if I can dig anything further. But what ewwhite asked are valid questions.

Comment: +1 for digging into actual source code for the command in question.

Comment: Great information, this is the kind of authoritative source I'm looking for.  Thank you for doing the hard work to find the code.

Answer (score 8):

**(1) Base on OP `last` output**

After log in via ssh, one can ssh to localhost and get 0.0.0.0 in `last -i` for the later.

Base on first four lines of OP's log

```
mpenning pts/19                        Fri Nov 16 10:32 - 10:35  (00:03)
mpenning pts/17                        Fri Nov 16 10:21 - 10:42  (00:21)
bill     pts/15       sol-bill.local   Fri Nov 16 10:19 - 10:36  (00:16)
mpenning pts/1        192.0.2.91       Fri Nov 16 10:17 - 10:49 (12+00:31)
```

`pts/19` log in was within `pts/17` log in period.

`pts/17` log in was within `pts/1`  log in period.

For this specific occurrence, it is logical to guess that OP ssh from 192.0.2.91(`pty/1`), then within that ssh session, log in locally (`ssh localhost`) to the server again(`pts/17`), and again(`pts/19`).

Please check if this overlapping happen with other occurrence.

Following may help pin point the cause

- Do you use ssh-key? If so, on the server, did you setup ssh-key to log in locally?
- **Check or post /var/log/secure of the same time frame. It may provide some hint.**
- Check scripts you use
- Check shell aliases you use
- Check your command history

**(2) Additional Secnario**

*Scenario 1 - sudo and terminal*

1. UserA login X Window
2. Open a terminal windows, do `xhost + localhost`
3. `su - UserB` or `sudo su - UserB` then open a new terminal (xterm, gnome-terminal, etc)
4. `UserB` will show up as 0.0.0.0 in `last -i`

`su - UserB` will not register as a `UserB` login in last, but opening a terminal will.

*Scenario 2 - login*

1. ssh into server
2. type `sudo login`
3. login as yourself
4. check `last` and `last -i`

`last` show no hostname or IP for the `login session`.
`last -i` will IP 0.0.0.0 for the `login session`.

```
john@U64D211:~$ last -5
john     pts/0                         Sun Dec 23 20:50   still logged in   
john     pts/0                         Sun Dec 23 20:50 - 20:50  (00:00)    
john     pts/0        :0               Sun Dec 23 20:50 - 20:50  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-35-generic Sun Dec 23 20:49 - 20:50  (00:01)    
john     pts/2        js.example.com   Sun Dec 23 17:14 - crash  (03:34)    

wtmp begins Sat Dec  1 06:30:46 2012
john@U64D211:~$ last -5i
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sun Dec 23 20:50   still logged in   
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sun Dec 23 20:50 - 20:50  (00:00)    
john     pts/0        0.0.0.0          Sun Dec 23 20:50 - 20:50  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sun Dec 23 20:49 - 20:50  (00:01)    
john     pts/2        192.168.1.90     Sun Dec 23 17:14 - crash  (03:34)    

wtmp begins Sat Dec  1 06:30:46 2012
```

**Mife**'s answer already show code block of `last.c`. The reason `last` display empty hostname/IP is because `ut_host` for those records are **actually** empty. For complete wtmp structure, do `man wtmp` on any linux system.

The 2 scenarios here shows that even standard packages, under certain situation, do create them as such.

**(3) Bash History Hack**

It will only work if the session use `bash` as interactive shell.

`.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` are only used by `bash`.

They won't be sourced automatically if the session use any other shell(sh, csh, etc) or execute program directly, and there will be no bash history either.

**(4) Process Accounting**

Since OP mention nothing about `secure` file, I will assume that is a dead end and it actually provide now hint.

If the following assumption is correct

```
`last` 0.0.0.0 entries are actually created with in OP own session
```

auth.log(debian)/secure(CentOS) will not help. As only authentication related action is recorded in it.

wtmp/utmp, with the limitation in their data structure, is also a dead end. There is no information about what created them.

That leave us with one option, [process accounting](http://www.linuxarticles.org/2010/10/observing-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct-2/). This is a big gun and has to be used with caution.

1. Maybe against company policy
2. Other users on a shared system maybe unhappy/uncomfortable with it enabled
3. The log file can use a lot of disk space. Keep an eye on the file size growth rate.

The psacct package version should be **6.3.2-56** or above, according to this [post](https://serverfault.com/a/334630/138643).

If this is to be used, and `/var/log` has limited space, change the acct log file to a directory(root only access) under `/home`, which usually has much more space.

This is really the big gun. With OP 10% occurrence rate, there should be result within a week. If during that period, empty entry show up in `last` but nothing from acct log, it become a **mystery** **situation**, and would require some **drastic action**.

Following is a sample output of `lastcomm`

```
lesspipe               john     pts/8      0.02 secs Mon Dec 24 17:10
lesspipe          F    john     pts/8      0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:10
dirname                john     pts/8      0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:10
basename               john     pts/8      0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:10
kworker/1:2       F    root     __         0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 16:54
tty                    john     pts/6      0.01 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
tty                    john     pts/4      0.01 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
cron              F    root     __         0.05 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
sh               S     root     __         0.01 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
find                   root     __         0.01 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
maxlifetime            root     __         0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
php5                   root     __         0.23 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
which                  root     __         0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:09
lastcomm               root     pts/0      0.01 secs Mon Dec 24 17:08
tty                    john     pts/1      0.01 secs Mon Dec 24 17:08
dconf worker         X john     __         5.46 secs Mon Dec 24 16:58
lastcomm               root     pts/7      0.04 secs Mon Dec 24 17:05
mesg             S     root     pts/7      0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:05
bash              F    root     pts/7      0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:05
dircolors              root     pts/7      0.00 secs Mon Dec 24 17:05
```

You can also use 'dump-acct' to show more info.

PS1: I tried to open a few terminal and ssh session. It is not clear (or not easy to pin point) what open a new pts. However, it does show everything that ran within that pts/session.

PS2: A [blog](http://beginlinux.com/blog/2010/01/monitoring-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct/) post about using acct by a Mike.

Comment: I dont know how you concluded tha a localhost login yields 0.0.0.0, it always shows up as localhost for me.  I only login with ssh, I dont know what you mean by login locally

Comment: Please do `ssh localhost` and check `last -i`.

Comment: Regarding `login locally`, I mean doing `ssh localhost` within that ssh session. I modified that sentence, hope it is less confusing now.

Comment: Additional scenario added.

Answer (score 8):

So I've ran last in a debugger which hopefully will give you at least *some* answers to your question. My feeling is the root cause is deeper though.

### **Why does last -i show 0.0.0.0 for pts line entries**

The best way to explain this is what happens when you **dont** pass -i.

The reason for this is in this code section of `last.c`

```
if (usedns || useip)
  r = dns_lookup(domain, sizeof(domain), useip, p->ut_addr_v6);
if (r < 0) {
   len = UT_HOSTSIZE;
   if (len >= sizeof(domain)) len = sizeof(domain) - 1;
   domain[0] = 0;
   strncat(domain, p->ut_host, len);
}
```

Both `usedns` and `useip` (using the default options) are not flagged. This causes the logic to copy out of the struct `p->ut_host` which according to `man utmp` contains the remote login name as recorded by whatever wrote into the `utmp`.

```
char ut_host[UT_HOSTSIZE]; /* Hostname for remote login, or
                              kernel version for run-level
                              messages */
```

In your case, the value in here is zeroes. This is why when you run `last` nothing appears for you.

In the case of `last -i` then dns_lookup is invoked. This will pass the entry (p->ut_addr_v6) to be resolved via DNS. In your case this value *also* contains zeroes.

Most of `dns_lookup` is window dressing and heusteric. Basically what matters is the function `getnameinfo`. This is a library call which in this case will try its best to resolve the binary value stored in the `ut_addr_v6`. When this entry contains zeroes (such as in your case) you are actually resolving this to `0.0.0.0` as is what happens with your `last -i` output.

### Is there anything (other than malicious activity) that would reasonably explain the behavior?

Well, its probably a bug or oversight. Its unlikely to be malicious since it seems stupid to leave *any* trace as an attacker rather than omitting a source address.

The focus of answers so far have been looking at the wrong place. `last` just reads `utmp` or `wtmp`. However `last` is doing its best with the data it has.

**Your root cause lies somewhere in the manner to which `utmp` is being written to**!

While a few applications directly write into `utmp` I guess the source of your problems lie in the way `sshd` is handling the session management.

### Other than bash history timestamping, are there other things I can do to track the issue down?

`utmp` is not typically writable and is not meant to be. `utmp` is written by applications designed to log you in and setup your session. In your case that is `sshd`.

Why sshd is not handling your user properly is very strange as it should be properly copying in the hostname you came in from. This is where debugging efforts should probably be focused. Start with adding debug output of sshd to your logs and see if anything anomalous comes up.

If you want to work around the problem (or, maybe even possibly discover more about the issue) you can use `pam_lastlog` to manage `utmp` by adding it to the *session* entry to /etc/pam.d/sshd.

As a matter of fact it wont hurt to check if it is already there -- because `pam_lastlog` contains a `nohost` option which would definitely explain your behaviour you are experiencing.

Finally, you could not use last at all. `aulast` does the same job via the audit subsystem.

Might be worth a try to see if that has managed to at least write the correct address. If it hasn't then your problem *must* be with sshd as sshd is passing the DNS names around different subsystems like utmp or audit.

Comment: Could you add some specific instructions on how to use `pam_lastlog` as mentioned above
?

Answer (score 5):

When you login to a Machine, these could be few entries in the last command.

```
geekride   tty2                        Fri Dec 21 15:45 - 15:45  (00:00)    
geekride   pts/1                       Fri Dec 21 13:45   still logged in   
geekride   pts/1        :pts/0:S.0     Thu Dec  6 12:49 - 00:40  (11:50)    
geekride   pts/1        10.31.33.47    Thu Dec  6 12:49 - 00:40  (11:50)
```

The First entry with tty* comes when you login through the terminal or console by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1-6. Its pretty much clear from the terminal it's using.

The second Entry normally comes into picture when you log into a Machine and open up a terminal window in GUI. There will also be a entry even if you open a new Tab in the same terminal window.

The Third type of Entry comes when you open a screen session after loggin into through SSH. That will also create a entry there and without any IP address.

The fourth entry is pretty normal which everyone understands.

If you do `last -i` with the following entries, you will see something like this:

```
geekride   tty2         0.0.0.0        Fri Dec 21 15:45 - 15:45  (00:00)    
geekride   pts/9        0.0.0.0        Fri Dec 21 13:45   still logged in   
geekride   pts/1        0.0.0.0        Thu Dec  6 12:49 - 00:40  (11:50)
```

I am pretty much sure that your case comes under in any of the 2 cases, one with the terminal Window in GUI and the other with the screen session.

Hope this Helped.

Comment: I did not use the GUI or `screen` for any of the `0.0.0.0` entries.  I only use the GUI when I installed the machines (around August / September).  I see many `0.0.0.0` pts entries after that time.

Comment: this was really useful and cleared few of really old doubts I had

Answer (score 3):

I checked across 12 multi-user CentOS and RHEL 6.3-based application servers. None exhibited this behavior. There were no missing entries in `last` output going back 4-5 weeks.

I think it would be important to see your `/etc/hosts` file entry to make sure it [conforms to this format](https://serverfault.com/questions/331936/setting-the-hostname-fqdn-or-short-name/331942#331942).

Also, what are you doing for DNS resolution? Can you post your `/etc/resolv.conf`?

The other responses indicating that `0.0.0.0` represents local connections are correct. The typical examples are reboot and console login events:

```
 reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sat Dec  8 06:12 - 05:57 (12+23:45)  
 reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sat Dec  8 05:25 - 06:09  (00:44)    
 reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Fri Nov 30 14:28 - 05:22 (7+14:54)   
 root     tty1         0.0.0.0          Fri Nov 30 13:52 - 13:55  (00:03)    
 reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Fri Nov 30 13:51 - 14:25  (00:34)
```

Since this only seems to occur with named users, is there any change there's something funky being sourced or run in their login scripts? Have you changed `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` from default? Are there any other special login scripts in the environment?

--Edit--

I'm still unable to reproduce this in any way. I look at two critical components, though. The `last` command is stable and has not been changed in a long time. Looking at the changelog for [sysvinit-tools](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/6.3/x86_64/Packages/sysvinit-tools-2.87-4.dsf.el6.x86_64.html), there are no relevant bugs. Same for [initscripts](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/updates/6.3/x86_64/Packages/initscripts-9.03.31-2.el6.centos.1.x86_64.html) (wtmp).

If you can force this to happen, try it with a different user account from the same source machines. But I don't see any indication that this is an OS issue.

Comment: Regarding your questions about the local environment... Please see the latest edits to my question... keep in mind that no other users have this issue besides me... so global configs (such as `/etc/hosts`) should affect everyone... not just me

Comment: It would be helpful to know what timeframe this occurred over. Your log snippet is a month old. Is this reproducible? Is this occurring on all servers? Perhaps if the wtmp file has been rotated, you may have a wtmp and wtmp1. Can you run `last -if` against both of those files and see if you see the same results over time?

Comment: Also, are you running commands; (p)sftp (p)scp? I ask since your no-IP sessions occur within the timeframe of a longer session. In your example, were you opening multiple connections from 192.0.2.91?

Comment: good questions... I have to prepare for guests arriving today but I will endeavor to respond with those details this weekend

Comment: I sometimes use scp and sftp via the free WinSCP client; however, those entries produce valid `/var/log/secure` entries... the entries which show `0.0.0.0` show nothing in `/var/log/secure`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we're going to get far with this without debugging last.c, but that shouldn't not too hard as it compiles readily ...

One possibility though is to dump the /var/log/wtmp file using the [utmpdump](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/1/utmpdump.htm?print=-51) command and have a look at the raw records this may shed some light for you. If not please post some relevant output from

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp
```

so that we can recreate local copies of your wtmp to debug with

```
utmpdump -r <dumpfile >wtmp
```

Comment: This may seem like it's not an answer but it really is, we've gone past the point of people just knowing this and really need to get debugging.

Comment: It's environment-specific. I run enough of these servers and can't reproduce the behavior with any combination of normal activity.

Comment: @ewwhite: I've a few too and I can't find it either.

Comment: @ewwhite Tried a few CentOS machines myself and asked also some colleagues that maintain about 300 of these boxes. They can't recall ever having seen this before either.

Answer (score 3):

### FINAL RESOLUTION

I already awarded the bonus, so this is purely for future googlers with the same question.

The reason this only appears in ~10% of my logins is because when I make major changes to our routers or switches, I use `script foo.log` so I have a complete terminal log of the change.  For reasons I still don't understand, CentOS creates a `pts` entry when you use the `script` command...  I will demonstrate the output of `last -i` before and after running `script`...

```
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ last -i | head
kkim14   pts/13       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/12       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/10       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/9        192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/5        192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
mpenning pts/17       192.0.2.29    Mon Dec 31 16:45 - 16:49  (00:03)
gduarte  pts/16       192.0.2.135   Thu Dec 27 10:54   still logged in
gduarte  pts/14       192.0.2.135   Thu Dec 27 10:44   still logged in
dspencer pts/14       192.0.2.4     Thu Dec 27 09:56 - 09:57  (00:01)
mpenning pts/14       192.0.2.91    Thu Dec 27 08:31 - 08:32  (00:00)
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ script ~/something_random.log
Script started, file is /home/mpenning/something_random.log
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ date
Thu Jan  3 16:14:19 CST 2013 # <--------------------------------------------------
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ exit
exit
Script done, file is /home/mpenning/something_random.log
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ last -i | head
mpenning pts/15       0.0.0.0          Thu Jan  3 16:14 - 16:14  (00:00) # <------
kkim14   pts/13       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/12       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/10       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/9        192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/5        192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
mpenning pts/17       192.0.2.29    Mon Dec 31 16:45 - 16:49  (00:03)
gduarte  pts/16       192.0.2.135   Thu Dec 27 10:54   still logged in
gduarte  pts/14       192.0.2.135   Thu Dec 27 10:44   still logged in
dspencer pts/14       192.0.2.4     Thu Dec 27 09:56 - 09:57  (00:01)
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
[mpenning@sasmars net]$
```

This behavior seems to be unique to CentOS 6... we have some CentOS 4.7 machines in the lab that don't put a blank entry in `wtmp`... Debian / Gentoo machines don't exhibit this behavior either.  Our linux-admins are scratching their heads why CentOS would intentionally add another `pts` entry when you execute `script`... I suspect this is a RHEL bug.

*EDIT*: I filed this problem as [**RHEL Bug id 892134**](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=892134)

### NOTE

Some people have erroneously assumed I put `script` in my `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.  This is a flawed argument... if that was true, my `wtmp` should have a `0.0.0.0` entry after every one of my ssh logins...

```
[mpenning@sasmars net]$ last -i | head
kkim14   pts/13       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/12       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/10       192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/9        192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
kkim14   pts/5        192.0.2.225   Wed Jan  2 09:43   still logged in
mpenning pts/18       0.0.0.0       Mon Dec 31 16:45 - 16:49  (00:03)  # <-----
mpenning pts/17       192.0.2.29    Mon Dec 31 16:45 - 16:49  (00:03)  # <-----
gduarte  pts/16       192.0.2.135   Thu Dec 27 10:54   still logged in
gduarte  pts/14       192.0.2.135   Thu Dec 27 10:44   still logged in
dspencer pts/14       192.0.2.4     Thu Dec 27 09:56 - 09:57  (00:01)
mpenning pts/15       0.0.0.0       Thu Dec 27 08:31 - 08:32  (00:00)  # <-----
mpenning pts/14       192.0.2.91    Thu Dec 27 08:31 - 08:32  (00:00)  # <-----
```

Of course, that was not the case...

Comment: You didn't mention that you were using the `script` command in your initial question.

Comment: That's a pretty lame complaint... blaming me for not mentioning this is Monday-morning QB-ing at its worst... if I knew `script` mattered, I would not need to ask the question

Comment: I asked *Have you changed ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile from default? Are there any other special login scripts in the environment?*. The `script` program makes a typescript of ***everything*** printed on your terminal. It's a pertinent detail.

Comment: @ewwhite it's time for you to stop attacking and start thinking critically... 1) You are assuming script was in my `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, it was not; I execute `script foo.log` when I make major changes so I can have a change-log... ie that's why it only affects ~10% of my logins 2) If your accusation is correct (and it's not), I would never have an ssh login that did not have another `0.0.0.0` entry just after it 3) `script` only does this in CentOS... I have used it for over a decade and never saw this behavior in another distro... at this point I'm arguing it is likely a CentOS bug

Comment: This is also present in CentOS 5.8. FWIW it wouldn't be a bug in CentOS it would be a bug in RHEL as CentOS is just a rebuild of that.

Comment: Fair point about RHEL bug... thanks for testing on 5.8... I will submit a ticket and see what happens

Comment: Thank you very very much for the update. I tested on Ubuntu 12.04, `script` will only fork a shell. Base on what you are showing here, CentOS/Redhat version of `script` actually fork a pty first. Though a bit disappointed (:P) that it is not something more generic/across distro, at least the mystery is gone from my mind. PS: I am surprise you have Gentoo in production @.@

Comment: @JohnSiu, Thank you for testing Ubuntu; had a feeling it wouldn't replicate CentOS' behavior since Ubuntu's development is so closely-linked to Debian.  Regarding Gentoo: our corporate linux preference *is* CentOS... however, one of our full-time linux admins runs Gentoo on his personal linux desktop because he feels that he learns so much about linux by running Gentoo...

Comment: @MikePennington: It's also present in Fedora BTW, Michael Hampton checks for me.

Comment: We'll follow the RHEL bug. It'll be interesting to see how they respond.

Comment: @MikePennington Check my new answer for the new mystery :)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo Terminal Slave (pts) connections are SSH or telnet connections that means indirect connections to the system. All of these connections can connect to a shell which will allow you to issue commands to the computer. So when you open up a terminal on your system from gui, it opens up a pts with source ip 0.0.0.0. From the information provided by you, it seems that it happening because of script running on this server or scheduled, which is using ssh or telnet service or local pts to throw output in terminal.

Comment: I never use the GUI

Answer (score 2):

Which ssh client do you use? Some ssh clients can multiplex multiple terminals over one connection and I notice all your sessions without IP fall within longer sessions which do have a logged IP.

I can't duplicate this behaviour with ssh here.

Comment: I usually use [superputty](http://code.google.com/p/superputty/), currently on version 1.4.0.1... but I have seen this issue with plain-ole putty as well

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your IP address resolves to a blank string on one of your DNS servers, probably the secondary if it happens only 10 per cent of the time (or just possibly a hosts file if these are distributed from a central repository). That would account for the missing (or white space) entry and be consistent with Soham's reading of the source.

Answer (score 0):

"0.0.0.0" means that's a local user (not a remote login), probably invoked by application e.g cronjob.

Comment: This answer [looks wrong](http://serverfault.com/a/95570/78702)... all 0.0.0.0 entries in my logs are *on a pts line*

Comment: It's a right answer, example from my system:
`# last -i |grep 0.0.0.0 \
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Wed Dec  5 20:09 - 17:18 (15+21:08)                                                          # last |grep reboot \
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-10-pve    Wed Dec  5 20:09 - 17:18 (15+21:08)`

Comment: @alterpub, again, I only login with ssh; 0.0.0.0 is not a valid ssh pty entry unless someone can show me *official documentation* otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you use local system and 0.0.0.0 means ip address of all interfaces.
If you think that maybe somebody hacked you try to setup full logging of shell including commands via ssh - http://blog.pointsoftware.ch/index.php/howto-bash-audit-command-logger/

Comment: What do you mean "you use local system"... please read my question closely... I **only** login with ssh.  Are you suggesting that 0.0.0.0 is a valid entry for an ssh login to a pty?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by adding a script to ~/.bashrc
the script finds the last telnet connection source IP address,
Then you can add the IP to a log file or do whatever you need..

```
client_ip=$(echo $(netstat -nae | grep $(netstat -nae | grep 23 | awk  '{print $8}' | sort -n | tail -n1) | awk '{print $5}') | awk -F':' '{print $1}' )

echo "client_ip=$client_ip"
```

Sharon

Comment: This answer does not make much sense to me. The discussion is not about telnet. `netstat -nae | grep 23` is not a useful way to find telnet connections. This command gives 92 results on my system, none of them being telnet.